# Pytorch - Intent creation data

Tags: pytorch, chatbot, openai-api, llama-index

I am trying to create a local chatbot based on:

- existing models (french language)
- customized models (custom confidential texts that I need to train)

As pythonic, PyTorch seems to be perfect with TorchText.

I am trying to reproduce the same kind of pipeline that I used with LLama (GPT Index) based on custom data and Open AI (but can't do it for confidentiality reasons because it sends my trained data to OpenAI trough API), with which I didn't had to create intents (tags, patterns, reponses...).

I feel a bit lost about with Pytorch, it seems that we need to create this kind of structure of intent, with potentials input patterns before to train them.

```
{
  "intents": [
    {
      "tag": "...",
      "patterns": [
       ...
      ],
      "responses": [
        ...
      ]
    },
}
```

I can't predict all input patterns. I just need to preprocess the all text to be used as a model.

Is it possible ?
Any tutorial suggestions ?

Comment: If this happens to be useful information, as of March 1st OpenAI no longer uses API data to train their model (https://help.openai.com/en/articles/7232945-how-can-i-use-the-chatgpt-api). They keep it for 30 days, I assume just to hold people accountable if they use it for nefarious purposes. I'm not 100% sure if I would trust them to keep it safe though, they had a leak not too long ago. https://www.reddit.com/r/technology/comments/122q7ql/openai_ceo_feels_awful_after_chatgpt_leaks/

Comment: That's a great point. The "data usage policy" is a 404 for the moment ^^ things are moving quick. Thanks for these informations.